# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in myfile.ovpn:1: ��c (2.5.8)

Tags: linux, openvpn, docker

I'll add the file's contents excluding the various secret contents

```
client
nobind
dev tun
remote-cert-tls server

remote myserver.com 1194 udp

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>

redirect-gateway def1
```

I'm just trying to hook up my client to a docker container w/ openvpn server running
https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn
and a separate container w/ DDNS server running
https://github.com/timothymiller/cloudflare-ddns/releases

Thanks,
Liam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you were editing the config file with some dumb text editor (Windows notepad?) who still doesn't know that use of BOM in UTF-8 files is [not needed](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5) (because they don't give user a choice of byte order, they're always in "network order"), and it put it in front of the file, just before the word 'client' (which is what "c" in the error message is from). OpenVPN doesn't expect those non-ASCII characters.

You have to use a decent editor and remove extra bytes before the first "c" in the file somehow.

Comment: This was it. I copied and pasted to contents into a new file and it ran properly. Thank you.